# Start up message: the Disk driver for /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 is not ready yet or not present

Tags: boot

When i start my Ubuntu (i have only Ubuntu, no other OS- **Lenevo B560**)the start screen displays this message. I have version 12.04, but initially when i install this there is no such message, but after downloading updates i got this message.The message is like below:-

the Disk driver for `/dev/mapper/cryptswap1` is not ready yet or not present.

continue to wait, or press S to skip mounting or M for manual recovery.

So it takes some more time to boot. I am a basic user having no knowledge about command lines. 
So please be slight not technical or exact step by step description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message indicates that the the system was unable to use its encrypted swap partition.

Not being able to use swap may cause slowdown, especially if your machine doesn't have much RAM installed.

Assuming the system is booting, you should be able to fix the problem without too much hassle.

**Step by step**

1. Boot and open a terminal (ctrl+alt+t)
2. Run this command `sudo gedit /etc/fstab`, a new window with the text
   editor should appear.
3. Change the line `/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0` to read
   `/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw,noauto 0 0`
4. Save
5. Back in the terminal run `sudo gedit /etc/rc.local` and add these
   two lines right after `exit 0`:

   ```
   sleep 5
   swapon /dev/mapper/cryptswap1
   ```

I hope this fixes your problem, good luck.

Comment: Thank You, Minnen, This was my first Question and i solved it with help from you. Sorry for delay in thanks giving as i have incorporated your suggestion now and its working

Comment: Im glad it solved your problem, pleas close the question by marking my answer as the solution